# jQuery Post Submitting Twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, formvalidation-plugin

I have a form that uses a formvalidation.io class. I Have a if statement that says if the field is valid use a jQuery post to submit the data and prepend the data on a table. For Some reason it is submitting twice. If I remove the $.post and prepend the data under the if statement the prepend only does one time. I have the e.preventDefault() at the start of the function. That seams to be the only solution on other forums.  Any Help Appreciated:

```
           barcode: {
            onSuccess: function(e, data) {
                e.preventDefault();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if (!$('#move_bin').data('formValidation').isValidField('bin')) {
                        $("#barcode").val("");
                        $('#move_bin').data('formValidation').updateStatus('barcode', 'NOT_VALIDATED');
                        $('#move_bin').data('formValidation').updateStatus('bin', 'INVALID');
                    } else {
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                if ($('#move_bin').data('formValidation').isValidField('barcode')) {
                                    $.post( "/?a=scantobin", { bin: $("#bin").val(), barcode: $("#barcode").val() }, function( data ) {
                                      if(data.valid == true){
                                        $("#bin_info tbody").prepend("<tr><td>" + $("#bin").val() + "</td><td>" + $("#barcode").val() + "</td></tr>");
                                        $('#move_bin').data('formValidation').resetField('barcode', true);
                                        $("#barcode").focus();  
                                      } else {
                                        alert("Internal Error");  
                                      }
                                    }, "json");
                                }
                            }, 750);
                    }
                }, 500);
            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://formvalidation.io/examples/form-submit-twice/

This helped me out. I had to place the code in a Form Level instead of the field level on the formvalidation.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your code, may be somewhere in your project you are invoking that function twice.